# Mahout slope one and categories

Tags: mahout

I would like to use slope one as item reccomender. The problem is that I have groups of items that are not correlated each other.It seems to me that there is no way to tell Mahout to use the diff storage just for a group of products.I want to achieve this because the groups have an average of 100 items and I prefer to not create a mongoDbDiffStorage from scratch. Does the rescorer tell what differences should be computed in order to avoid to store useless data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean that you know that you want to consider some items completely unrelated? No, you'd have to write your own `DiffStorage` for that.

Or, I might suggest that if these item sets are completely unrelated, then what you really have is a recommender problem for each group of items, and can use a `Recommender` for each subset of data. This would probably be easier and more efficient in many ways.

Comment: If the items in the group are about 100, could it be feasible to build a new slope reccomender at each request with a memory diff storage?

Comment: Maybe, but why do that? build one per group and reuse it.